# Send mail to the System Administrator

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

I have tried this to send mail to the logged in user

```
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {UserInfo.getUserEmail()};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
```

This works fine for the users who have logged in, but I would like to send mail only to **System Administrator**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean send mail only if the user is System Administrator?

Comment: Whoever logs in I want the mail to be send mail to the system admin irrespective of whoever the user be.@SantanuHalder

Comment: than query users with System Admin profile and use their email. like - Profile p = [SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE name = 'System Administrator'];  Users[] u_to_send = [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE ProfileId = :p.Id];
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {u_to_send.get(0).Email};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
but I would recommend to use setTargetid of user to avoid limit of sending direct emails to addresses

Comment: it worked fine @kurunve. Thanks. Can you post this as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic idea would be to query user that you need (f.e. with system admin profile etc), and use email on that field. 
For example:

```
Profile sys_adm_profile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
List<User> sys_adm = [SELECT id, Email FROM User WHERE ProfileId = :sys_adm_profile];
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {sys_adm.Email};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
```

There is better approach -- as well as email is being send to user, then **mailsetTargetObjectId(userId)** should be used to avoid limits of email that can be send for different email addresses.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section

Also those method of getting system admin profile is not perfect -- it would fail in orgs with non english language.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with just **one** query:

```
SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
```

Answer (score 0):

//if person select other gender then send email to system adiminstrator
public class personClassHandler {

```
public static void sendEmailongenderselection(List<Person__c>newList,List<Person__c>oldList){
    
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  
    
    if(trigger.isAfter &&(trigger.isInsert||trigger.isUpdate)){
        for(Person__c p:newList){
            if(p.Gender__c=='Others'){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                
                List<String>toAddresses = new List<String>{};   
            
   List<User>u = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'];
                for(user ui:u){
                  toAddresses.add(ui.Email);
                }
                
          
          mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                String body = 'Some one has selected others gender';
                mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                mails.add(mail);
                System.debug('mails'+mails);
            }
            messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).