# trigger for email notification to admin on account creation

Tags: trigger, singleemailmessage

write a trigger so that Once an account is created an email should go to the admin user

--------helper -----

```
public class AccountEmailHelper
{
public static List<account> sendEmail(List<account> accounts)
 {
     EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'new account'];
     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

      for (Account acc:accounts )
      {
       if (acc.Email != null && acc.Name != null) 
        {
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         singleMail.setTargetObjectId(user.Id);
         singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
         singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
         emails.add(singleMail);
         }
        }
     Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
     return accounts;

    }
}
```

trigger below ;;;;;

```
trigger AccountEmail on Account (after insert) 
{
if(Trigger.isAfter)
       {
        if(Trigger.isInsert )
          { 
          AccountEmailhelper.sendEmail(trigger.new);
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error message? If so please add that to the question as it helps identify where the error is in the code.

Comment: Did you get any error? One thing to not is Account object don't have `Email` standard field

Comment: its not working ...not getting an error there is no mail going to system admin aftr account is created i want a trigger which sends a email to system admin whenever a new account is created

Comment: why don't you use Workflow here?

Comment: my requirement is by use of  trigger

Comment: I still don't see why this can't be a workflow rule. Using a workflow rule on the Account object that triggers **on create** of a new record and sends an email alert to whatever email address or email addresses you designate. Your code isn't doing anything special (at least not the code you provided in your example) that should warrant a trigger being required. **always clicks before code. When the platform provides an easier way to do something, do it**

Answer (score 1):

In such situations, when you receive no errors, but your code still doesn't work as you expected - put several System.debug() methods, put your variables here to see their values during execution(like `System.debug(acc)`), OR just write any string to make sure that your code reached this system debug, i.e. `System.debug('My code reaches here')`. I inserted System.debug methods into your code below.

```
public class AccountEmailHelper
{
public static List<account> sendEmail(List<account> accounts)
 {
     EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name=:'new account'];
     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

      for (Account acc:accounts )
      {
       if (acc.Email != null && acc.Name != null) 
        {
         System.debug('This debug allows me to understand that I have at least 1 account with not empty email and name');
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         String[] toAddresses = new String[] {acc.Email};
         singleMail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
         singleMail.setTargetObjectId(user.Id);
         singleMail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
         singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
         emails.add(singleMail);
         }
        }
     System.debug('And this debug will allow you to understand if your emails list is not empty ' + emails);
     Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
     return accounts;

    }
}
```

And the obvious problem in your code is that you're not assigning `setToAddresses()` variable. In the code above I added rows that should dismiss the problem.

Comment: its showing error now     Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setTargetObjectId(Schema.SObjectField) at line 16 column 10

Comment: What error does it show? Try to not forget to post the error as soon as you receive it, it saves time and allows to provide you solution faster.

Comment: I reviewed the code and removed possible errors. Try again.

Comment: there is no email field on account its error again no email field found on object

Comment: There is no standard email field on account. If you need an email field on account then you can add it to the object and reference as say acc.email__c - but the reference to acc.email was in your code sample.

Comment: @rahulgupta then you have to pass admin's email to toAddresses variable.

Comment: i m not getting can you please tell me in details

Comment: can someone give me full code ... rather than editing mine

Comment: @rahulgupta stackexchange is not about providing full and correct code/solutions by your requests, but rather a platform to help developers/consultants/enthusiasts where to look and what to read in order to solve their problem.

Comment: so in that case code what is the error how to sort it out

Comment: me and Dave wrote before that account doesn't have email field and you need to put somehow admin's email to toAddresses variable. Either hardcode or pull it somehow from system admin user's email.

Answer (score 0):

This value:

```
User.Id
```

is an [SObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm) token that represents the field itself not the value of the field.

To set a specific Id you could user `UserInfo.getUserId()` but that is the User that initiated the transaction. To get a "System Administrator" User you will have to query - see e.g. [Send mail to the System Administrator](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106023/send-mail-to-the-system-administrator).